# Not getting output from For /F - command promt

Tags: command-line, batch-file, command-prompt

I need to extract the service name only(basically display name) . I tried to use the following command but the command prompt is not showing any thing. Am i missing something?

```
 FOR /F "delims= " %A IN ('sc queryex type= service state= all ^| find "WIN" ') DO @echo %A
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Writing the output of `sc` to a temporary file and search that file works well:

```
>%TEMP%\~sc.log (sc queryex type= service state= all)
for /F "tokens=1,* delims=: " %%I in ('type %TEMP%\~sc.log^|findstr "DISPLAY_NAME"') do echo %%J
```